# Get date and time when photo was taken

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to rename few images by their date and time taken.

Is there a way to get the date and time when photo was taken using Mathematica?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WL supports access to image EXIF, IPTC and XMP data. e.g. to get the date/time from EXIF:

```
Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", "Exif"]["DateTime"] // DateString
(* Tue 19 Aug 2008 11:29:05 *)
```

Check the Scope and Import Elements sections of the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JPEG.html) for details.

Comment: You can also get it directly: `Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", "DateTime"]`

Comment: @C.E. Do you know if that is the EXIF or IPTC or XMP date/time? I looked at the documentation and did not find an answer.

Comment: It is Exif. If you look at the documentation for JPEG, Import Elements -> Available Elements -> Metadata -> Exif, you will find an example like the one I posted with the text "Individual Exif tags can also be imported directly".

Comment: Thanks for the solution which works great. Do you know if we can get Date and time for .Mp4 and .Mov? I tried the method but it didn’t work